# Trouble limiting the number of tags in a TagInputField

Tags: extjs, aem

According to [the documentation of the `TagInputField` widget](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.tagging.TagInputField), it should possible to limit the number of tags the user is allowed to use from every namespace in AEM tags.

> `namespaces` : *Array*
>
> A list of the tag namespaces that should be displayed and allowed. If empty, all available namespaces will be allowed. Otherwise either an array of Strings (the namespace names) or for more configuration an array of objects as this:

```
{
    name: "namespace",
    maximum: 1 // maximum number of tags allowed from this namespace; if -1 no limit (default)
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work when I try doing it.

In my scenario, I want to limit the user to a single namespace and only allow her/him to choose one tag.

When I only specify the namespace in my `dialog.xml`, the `namespaces` setting is respected:

```
<tags
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  allowBlank="true"
  fieldLabel="Tags"
  namespaces="[topics]"
  name="./tags"
  xtype="tags"/>
```

the widget only displayed the tags from `my-namespace`

Trouble starts when I try to limit the number of tags from this namespace.

```
<tags
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  allowBlank="true"
  fieldLabel="Tags"
  namespaces="[{name: &quot;topics&quot;, maximum: 1}]"
  name="./tags"
  xtype="tags"/>
```

This simply gets ignored and it seems something is off after the content gets imported into AEM using vault. When I inspect it in CRXDE, it looks like a String array with two values.

[image]

The behaviour of the dialog seems to confirm that it's more than a problem with the way it's displayed in CRXDE because no namespace is displayed by the widget.

[image]

Even if I manually edit the String array in CRXDE to have the right value (see the screenshot below), the dialog does not pick up any namespaces (same as above)

[image]

Has anyone had luck using this widget in the way described above? Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague just got back to me with an answer. It turns out I misunderstood the docs. The configuration (if used in the complex format) actually expects a nested structure of JCR nodes.

Therefore, in my `dialog.xml` I needed an additional node:

```
<tags
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  allowBlank="true"
  fieldLabel="Tags"
  name="./tags"
  xtype="tags">
    <namespaces jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <topics jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" maximum="1" name="topics" />
    </namespaces>
</tags>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<tags
  jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
  fieldLabel="Tags"
  name="./tags"
  xtype="tags">

    <namespaces jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <topic1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" maximum="3" name="topic1" />
        <topic2 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" maximum="3" name="topic2" />

    </namespaces>
</tags>
```

Link: - **http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__5hd0-hi_all_in_ourco.html**

Also have a look at this old post:- **https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1175413**

//

```
<locationTag jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" allowBlank="{Boolean}false"  
       cls="cq-propsdialog-tags" fieldLabel="Campus Location"  
       fieldDescription="Specify a campus location" name="./locationID/cq:tags"  
                                                  xtype="tags">  
       <namespaces jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">  
            <ns1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" maximum="1"  name="campuses" />  
       </namespaces>  
  </locationTag>
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks and Regards
Kautuk Sahni